# SharePoint 2019 shows logged in user under a different user account

Tags: user-profile

We just upgraded to SharePoint 2019 and share one of the web applications externally using CloudFlare. We can login to external sites correctly but the login name changes to a different user name after a few minutes, usually the last person that was active on the site.

Below are the error message.

```
A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure
Process Name: w3wp
Process ID: 9128
AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/SecurityTokenServiceApplication-1-133551015582757561
AppDomain ID: 2
Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:7def4e6a6a504272908e05992d1fd3ff#authority=urn:uuid:513d422ce418409eb63874c9c60734ea&authority=https://ecspapp01:32844/Topology/topology.svc
Active Endpoints: 1
Failed Endpoints:1
Affected Endpoint: http://webapp.local:32843/7def4e6a6a504272908e05992d1fd3ff/ProfileService.svc
----------------------------------------
ChannelInvoke::GetUserData::1 -- CommunicationException occurred: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfileDBCacheService.GetUserData(UserSearchCriteria searchCriteria)     at 
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetUserData>b__0(IProfileDBCacheService channel)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Infrastructure.ChannelInvoke`1.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, Action`1 codeBlock, ChannelInvokeSettings channelInvokeSettings)
```